# Calculate the discount rate

Tags: vb.net

I have the original price of a commodity and its discounted price.
I currently have some code but it is not working properly.

For example: The price of a pre-discounted commodity is 853.2 $.
The discounted price is 349 $.
That is a 59% discount, but my code shows the wrong numbers.

```
Dim a1 As String = (Val(pre-discounted_price) - Val(discount_price) * 100 / Val(discount_price)).ToString

Dim a2 As Integer = (853.2 - 349) * 100 / 349
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for calculating how much you need to discount something by, to reach a new price is:

```
100 * (originalprice - newprice) / originalprice

100 * (852.3 - 349) / 852.3 = 59 (0 decimal places)

Checking:
852.3 - (852.3 * 0.59) = 349 (approx)
```

Your code went wrong because you divided by the newprice